# Perl throws undefined subroutine in module instead of correct error

Tags: perl, perl-module

I've moved part of a script into a module, and now the only error I get when I do something wrong is "Undefined subroutine", even when the real error is that I misspelled a variable, or forgot a closing paren, or left off a semi-colon.

The only way to find the real error is to copy the entire thing into a script and run it that way. It's very tedious. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just the way modules are supposed to work?

Here is a very simple example that shows the problem:

Module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

package CalledError;
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK=qw(do_build_stor_pools);

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

sub do_build_stor_pools {
    say "now in CalledError do_build_stor_pools";

    #my $undef_var="uncomment this to fix";
    say $undef_var;

    return;
}
```

Calling script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

my $buildstor_mod="CalledError";
eval "require $buildstor_mod";
$buildstor_mod->import();

CalledError::do_build_stor_pools();
```

Run it like this to get 
`Undefined subroutine &CalledError::do_build_stor_pools called at calling_test.pl line 11.`

Uncomment the definition of `$undef_var` to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you checked $EVAL_ERROR, you would see the real error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

my $buildstor_mod="CalledError";
eval "require $buildstor_mod";
if ($@) {
   die "$@";
}
$buildstor_mod->import();

CalledError::do_build_stor_pools();
```

Error message:

```
Global symbol "$undef_var" requires explicit package name at CalledError.pm line 15.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1) line 2.
```

You see the undefined subroutine error because [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) fails.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had tried that at one point, but I must not have done it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You're not checking the error condition of your [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
eval "require $buildstor_mod";
die $@ if $@;
```

However, to load a module, you should just use [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CalledError qw(do_build_stor_pools);

do_build_stor_pools();
```

Outputs:

```
Global symbol "$undef_var" requires explicit package name at CalledError.pm line 14.
```

Comment: I can't use `use` because the file name for the package is going to vary depending on environmental settings. That's why I'm using `eval "require $var";` to load the package.

Comment: To use Environment specific modules, I would suggest using the [`if`](http://perldoc.perl.org/if.html) pragma.

Comment: There are many alternate module names; they are easily constructed using variables, but I don't think I can use a variable with `if`.

Comment: @Adina, you can use any arbitrary expression (including variables) to specify the module name with `if`.

Comment: @tobyink, I just tried using a variable with `use if`, and as far as I can tell, that's evaluated at compile-time and therefore variables aren't initialized. I might be able to get around that with a `BEGIN`block, but since I don't want to load this module at compile-time, there's not a lot of point to that.

Comment: Well, yes, the variable needs to be defined before you can use it. You can even do something like `use if 1, do { ...; $modulename }` where the `...` is a big block of code that figures out what module to load.

Comment: I just tried
    `use if 1, do {
        my $modname="CalledError";
        $modname;
    }`
and got `Useless use of private variable in void context at calling_error.pl line 30.`

Comment: You would still need to specify which functions to import, because you're not specifying anything for `@EXPORT` in the imported module.  The following works on my system `use if $ENV{USER} eq 'miller', CalledError => qw(do_build_stor_pools);`  Obviously the COND should be modified to match your needs.